Accidetally deleted the /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources file after the upgrade, how can I restore it?
I accidentally upgraded by running my upgrade script (it has since been banished). Post-upgrade I made the situation worse by deleting the ubuntu.sources file.
Now when I run sudo apt update I get
N: Missing Signed-By in the sources.list(5) entry for 'https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu'

I've tried adding the
Signed-By: /usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg

as suggested by some other users but that gives me this error
Err:2 https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu noble-apps-security InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY AB01A101DB53907B

I've also tried recreating the default ubuntu.sources file with this
Types: deb
URIs: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
Suites: noble noble-updates noble-backports
Components: main restricted universe multiverse
Signed-By: /usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg

Types: deb
URIs: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
Suites: noble-security
Components: main restricted universe multiverse
Signed-By: /usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg

But then it claims that I have packages configured multiple times.
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources:1


The "multiple times" error gives you the exact files that have the duplicate entries in them. Remove one of the entries.

Visit this site: https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/, in the generated file change bionic, the last accepted one, to noble on each line.
